# Setting up Dojo Release 1.5.0

Tags: dojo

I donwloaded this release, and I'm trying to run an example from the docs.
After expanding the Dojo download, my dojo dir is:

```
js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit
js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojo
js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojox
```

The buttons show up, but hide button does not hide the div.
Do I need to add other Dojo libraries along with the reference to dojo.js?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"  src="/js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var node = dojo.byId("findMe");
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("buttonOne"), "onClick", function() {
        dojo.fadeOut({
            node: node,
            duration: 300
        }).play();
    });
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("buttonTwo"), "onClick", function() {
        dojo.fadeIn({
            node: node,
            duration: 300
        }).play();
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="buttonOne">
Hide Me!
</button>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="buttonTwo">
Show Me!
</button>
<div id="findMe">
Hiya!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you may be missing. As Daniel says, adding `parseOnLoad=true` as a djConfig param will help. Alternatively you can add djConfig params as a global JS variable before your dojo.js script tag, i.e.

```
<script>
  var djConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>
```

A final alternative is to manually call the parser yourself. To do this, modify your JS to:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
// You need to manually require the parser if you're going to call it yourself
dojo.require("dojo.parser");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var node = dojo.byId("findMe");
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("buttonOne"), "onClick", function() {
        dojo.fadeOut({
            node: node,
            duration: 300
        }).play();
    });
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("buttonTwo"), "onClick", function() {
        dojo.fadeIn({
            node: node,
            duration: 300
        }).play();
    })

    // New line, parse the doc
    dojo.parser.parse();
});
```

Additionally to parsing, you may need to add a theme (you've not mentioned if you've done this or not). The easiest way to do this is to add the class name to your body tag and import the css.

```
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
</head>
<body class="claro">
  ...
</body>
```

http://telliott.net/dojoExamples/dojo-buttonHelloWorld.html contains an example of this all working for you, feel free to go crib.

Reading http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/djConfig.html#djconfig and http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/info.html#dijit-info would probably be a good idea also.

HTH.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

try adding djConfig="parseOnLoad:true" when add the dojo.js to the page.

ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"  src="/js/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
```

//Daniel